# How to identify which command PSEXESVC is running?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-services, psexec

I'm trying to spam a script using PsExec in several servers, the problem is that sometimes I get the error `the handle is invalid` that has a return code 6, but I don't know if this is a valid psexec process running on server or if, for some reason, an error ocurred and the PSEXESVC is hanging. In some servers the service is running forever.

My question is if there is a way to check which script/command the PSEXESVC is running to decide if I can kill it or not.

Comment: Do you mean a way for you to check, interactively, or a way for an unattended program to check?  Interactively, you could try using `pslist -t` to see whether psexesvc has a child process or not.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I think this will help .... But the hability to check by an unattended program is what I was looking for ...